# Is there an equivalent to Python ASGI in Java?

Tags: python, java, web-applications, wsgi, asgi

In Python as we have WSGI or ASGI which differ in the way they handle the incoming requests to the web application, is there a **Java equivalent** to these two varying methodologies?